# Goutte scraping google ppa php

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors, goutte

I want to create scrap PPA google using Goutte
this code is working fine, but why I cannot get only PPA results?

```
$data = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.google.co.in/search?ix=nh&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+developer');
$data->filter('html >body >div > div > div > div > div > div>div>div:nth-child(1)')->each(function ($node) {
    print_r($node->text()."<br><br>");
});
```

[image]

The red box is only what I want to get.
Are my selector is wrong?

[image]

and now i change the selector to `html>body>div>div>div> div> div`
and the results is

[image]

Comment: And what do you actually get instead? Also we can't see enough of the HTML structure to be sure what you'll select. Paste the HTML into the question instead of showing a truncated screenshot.

Comment: this not html, this code run on php. I have give the code.

Comment: Yes you have. But as I said, it doesn't show the `<html>` tag so we can't trace your selector properly through the HTML to know if you structured it correctly. And as per [ask] you should not be posting pictures of code anyway. [edit] the question to show a complete [mre] of the target HTML, as text.

Comment: sorry but this not me who give the html tag, I just put PHP tag.  Maybe this you wanted ? `http://www.google.co.in/search?ix=nh&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+developer` I have give the link on my script

Comment: Huh? No I mean this screenshot you posted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MHSv.png doesn't contain all of the HTML that you're trying to select from in your PHP. So we can't see if your selector is correct or not. Post all the HTML instead of just a sample. Don't expect us to go and scrape it from the page ourselves, that's not how Stackoverflow works. Make it easy for people to help you by providing all the necessary data within your question.